# Is there possible to make seperate InkWell Button with Firebase? Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile-development

I am new on Flutter, trying to do project with firebase. In my code, I can write screen only one InkWell with card, when i try to add another InkWell, project showing error.
So how can i add more than one InkWell
Here is my code;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/home.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'YOS APP',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: Home());
  }
}
```

Here is my tabbar page;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class TabBar1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabBar1({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('mat1').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: Text('Loading..'));
        }
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            children: snapshot.data.documents
                .map(
                  (doc) => InkWell(onTap: () {}, child MyCard(
                    title: doc['konu'],
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const MyCard({
    Key key,
    this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When i trying to put MyCard() widget into map area, an error occurs.

```
         .map(
              (doc) => MyCard(
                title: doc['konu1'],
              ),
              (doc)=> MyCard(title: doc['icerikler1'],)
            )
            .toList(),
```

error;
Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
InkWell(onTap: () {}, child: MyCard(
                    title: doc['konu'],
```

Instead of:

```
InkWell(onTap: () {}, child MyCard(
                    title: doc['konu'],
```

There must be a colon (:) at the child.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `map` takes only one argument ie. callback function which can return a single widget for every document in the list. If you want to return more than widget from map(), you can wrap multiple widgets in `Column` or `Row` widget according to your need.

Suppose if you want to use `Column`, you can do like this

```
snapshot.data.documents
    .map(
      (doc) => Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: MyCard(
              title: doc['konu1'],
            ),
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: MyCard(
              title: doc['icerikler1'],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
    .toList();
```

Comment: Glad that it worked. If the answer was helpful. Please upvote.